# Prevent accessing XAMPP localhost from another local PC by IP

Tags: xampp, localhost

It is well known how to access XAMPP sites from another computer in the local network (by typing IP address), please tell me how to FORBID to do so and still have a running localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost (127.0.0.1 for IPv4) is only accessible from, well, the local host.  Look for any "Listen" and "VirtualHost" directives and make sure they all say "localhost" and not another hostname or IP address.

Comment: thx, but no luck, I have searched httpd.conf and httpd-xampp.config for something similar :( any other clues where it can be?

Comment: Yep sorry, httpd.conf uncomment line with #Listen 127.0.0.1:80

Answer (score 1):

Thats so simple,

just create a file named  **index.php/index.html**

and just leave them empty,

now anybody who access your ip will be redirected to index.php and they can't be aware of what files you have.

Hope this answer helps.